# Python - read numbers from text file and put into list

Tags: python

So like the title says im starting to learn some python and im having trouble picking up on this technique.  What I need to accomplish is to read in some numbers and store them in a list.  The text file looks like the following:

```
0 0 3 50

50 100 4 20
```

Basically these are coordinates and directions to be used for python's turtle to make shapes.  I got that part down the only problem is getting them in a correct format. So what I can not figure out is how to get those numbers from the file into `[ [0, 0, 3, 50], [50, 100, 4, 20] ]`
A list, with each four coordinates being a list in that one big list.

Heres my attempt but it as I said I need some help - thank you.

```
polyShape=[]
infile = open(name,"r")
num = int(infile.readline(2))
while num != "":
    polyShape.append(num)
    num = int(infile.readline(2))
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    polyShape = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split() # to deal with blank 
        if line:            # lines (ie skip them)
            line = [int(i) for i in line]
            polyShape.append(line)
```

will give you

```
[[0, 0, 3, 50], [50, 100, 4, 20]]
```

This will work with a file that contains blank lines (or not).

Using the `with` construct will close the file for you automatically when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there isn't actually a blank line in your input file:

```
with open(name, "r") as infile:
    polyShape = [map(int, line.split()) for line in infile]
```

Explanation: `map(int, line.split())` splits each `line` and converts each part to an `int`. The `[X for Y in Z]` construct is a list comprehension that in turn maps the `map` over all lines of the file and returns its results in a list.

If you find this too complicated for now, then the `map(int, line.split())` is the main take-home message.

Comment: `map(int, line.split())` is like Python poetry. It even rhymes.

Comment: map() doesn't work, it is not executed.  The result is: [<map object at 0x108c66fd0>, <map object at 0x108c76080>, <map object at 0x108c760f0>].   The solution that works is Levon's

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lis=[map(int,x.split()) for x in f if x.strip()]   # if x.strip() to skip blank lines

   #use list(map(int,x.split()))  in case of python 3.x
```

this is how `map()` works:

```
>>> map(int,'1 2 3 4'.split())
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the file would be the easiest way:

```
poly_shape = []

with open(name, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if not line.strip():
            continue  # This skips blank lines

        values = map(int, line.split())
        poly_shape.append(values)
```

Comment: why `line.split(' ')` instead of `line.split()`?

Comment: I like to be verbose. `line.split()` doesn't explicitly tell you what you're splitting by.

Comment: .. but now there can't be two spaces or the code breaks.  I think I like the behaviour of `.split()` better, but YMMV.

Comment: @Blender: `line.split()` is not the same as `line.split(' ')`. It handles multiple spaces and tabs too.

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks, I didn't know that. I thought `' '` was the default argument. Fixed.

Comment: @Blender -- `line.split()` is the same as `line.split(None)` which splits on any consecutive runs of whitespace.  It is useful to know that `None` can be used if you also want to specify the "maxsplit" argument.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
[ [int(x) for x in line.split(' ')] for line in open(name,'r').readlines() if line.strip()]
```

but the `readlines` part is probably not a great idea.

I'm quite sure that `[int(x) for x in ... ]` is faster than using `map` as in other suggested solutions.

**Edit**

Thanks to Blender : no need for `.readlines`, which is cool, so we just have :

```
[ map(int, line.split()) for line in open(name,'r') if line.strip()]
```

I also used `map(int, )` because it's actually faster, and also you can use just `line.split()` instead of `line.split(' ')`.

Comment: Also, `map` is around 15 times faster than the list comprehension for me. Try timing it.

Comment: Nicely streamlined and very pythonic

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using `append` for a big array. It's 50 time slower than creating a zero array and assigning values to it.

```
import numpy
fname = "D:\Test.txt";
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(fname));
array = numpy.zeros((num_lines,4));
k = 0;
with open(fname, "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        a =[int(i) for i in line.split(' ')];;
         array[k,0:4] =a;
         k = k+1;
print(array)
```