# Need suggestions on creating lists from image

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, filter

So, what I have to do is to open an image in argv[1] and apply a filter argv[2]

The image file looks like this in txt:

```
P2
10 4
255
120 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
120 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 
120 0 0 0 0 0 255 255 0 0 
120 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

what I have to do is to organize the lines after the 255 in lists of lists, but all I can do is a list of strings, from which I can't do much (I will have to apply a filter and so on, but that is another problem.)

i should only use the sys library (it's an assignment)

```
import sys

class image:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.cab=[]
        self.img=a
        self.img2=[]
        self.c=[]
        for i in self.img:
            self.img2.append(i)
        self.img3=''.join(self.img2)
        self.img4=self.img3.split('\n')
    def cabec(self,b): # this has no importance in my question (only for the assignment)
        for i in range(3):
            self.c.append(b[i])

class filtro:
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.filt=[]
        for x in f:
            self.filt.append(x)
        self.filt2=''.join(self.filt)
        self.filt3=self.filt2.split('\n')

a = open(sys.argv[1])
b = image(a)
```

... (this is where I should be able to apply the filters and such, but with a list of strings I don't know what to do)

I am really an amateur, any suggestions would be nice

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need a list of ints instead of a list of strings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271503/python-read-numbers-from-text-file-and-put-into-list) for how to read ints from a text file.